# Dart language arrow keys event

Tags: dart, dartium

i'm trying to develop a simple application in dart, and i want to catch the arrow keys press 
event, i tried to add a onKeyPress event:

```
window.on.keyPress.add(myKeyDownEvent);

void myKeyDownEvent(Event event){
  query("#text").text = event.type.toString();  
}
```

It works with all keypress except arrow keys what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [a issue on chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2606) for that with **WontFix** status. Comment 5 says :

> This is done to match IE. keypress events are only supposed to fire for keys that insert 
>   characters. Note that keydown/keyup do fire for arrow keys.

Using `window.on.keyDown` instead of `window.on.keyPress` works for me.